Can I make JSDoc trust me that 1 egg + 1 egg = 2 eggs?
I want to write nC = nA + nB (see below) but JSDoc thinks that is an error. Can I make JSDoc change its mind?
/** @typedef {number&{_tag: 'numberOfEggs'}} numberOfEggs */

/** @param {number} value */
const numberOfEggs = (value) => /** @type numberOfEggs */(value);

/** @type {numberOfEggs} */
let nA = numberOfEggs(1);

/** @type {numberOfEggs} */
let nB = numberOfEggs(1);

/** @type {numberOfEggs} */
let nC = nA + nB;

// For nC I get this JSDoc error:
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'numberOfEggs'. ts(2322)

Playground

I guess the problem here are not types but the + operator that is supposed to always result in primitive number value. I'm afraid that to make this work and preserve the augmented primitive type (what I didn't know is even possible) we'd have to implement such arithmetic in typed functions.

@myf Thanks. Is this because TypeScript + operator always returns a primitive number? Or is this a problem with JSDoc?

Your question has nothing to do with TypeScript. Why do you use JSDoc instead of TypeScript?

@jabaa (not OP, but) 1) using JSDoc technically is using TS under the hood, just skipping the transpilation step, so it 2) clearly has its advantages. Could you make it work in TypeScript? Show us: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?&filetype=ts#code/C4TwDgpgBAdgrgWwEYQE4HkBmBRA5rgZygF5ZEVUoAyKAbwH1gBDXALigHJ5k0s9COAXwBQwgMYB7GAWBkeGHPiKkAFADcmAGzgR23CgEoSAPijqtOqEyL7eiwgYDcozRFkwAgiTkU+SlQCMTsIA9CFQUAB6APzCru4AQt62CvwEgcFhETEubrAAwqwpfoTJXgDUsAnOWVGx8bAAImVQlTDVoeF1wkA

Related: Does Typescript have Operator Overloading?

@jabaa I don't have much time for programming. To not waste my time I try to stay as close to more official standards with long life. The problem I asked about here seems to be related to difficult decisions in the implementation of the TypeScript compiler. I expect my problem will be fixed, but waiting for that I hoped that there was some kind of workaround.
